# Validating e-mail address syntax

Tags: jquery, contact-form

I'm building a contact form from scratch with some simple but fancy animations like animated checkmarks, animated Send button, mouseenter/mouseleave animated fields, etc. Meanwhile I'm writing the validation code and I'm having a bit of a difficulty with the email field. I've been checking other posts and googling for helpfull info, but my context is a bit peculiar.
Here's the code:

```
// Check if the email address is valid
function checkValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

// Email field validation
$('#userEmail').blur(function(){
  $(this).animate({'background-color':'#ffffff'}, 200);
  if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
    emailInvalidation();
    $('#inputText_infoBox p').html('Não se esqueça do seu e-mail!');
  }
  else{
    emailValidation();
    $('#inputText_infoBox p').html('O endereço de e-email parece válido');
  }
});
```

As you see, I'm doing the validation on blur(), specifically checking if the field is not empty - question: how do I contextualize the **checkValidEmailAddress** in the blur function? Where and how do I put it?

Thank you.

Pedro

Comment: What exactly are the functions `emailInvalidation();` and `emailValidation();` doing?

Comment: Those are some neat checkmark animations. The idea is if the input fields meet the requirements, than they animate to green (default: grayed out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to put it in your `else` statement and pass the value of your field as an argument; your code will look like this:

```
$('#userEmail').blur(function(){
  $(this).animate({'background-color':'#ffffff'}, 200);
  if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
    $('#inputText_infoBox p').html('Não se esqueça do seu e-mail!');
  }
  else{
    // Here you are passing the field value to the checkValidEmailAddress
    // function, which will return true if the pattern is found, or false
    // if it is not.
    if( checkValidEmailAddress( $(this).val() ) ) 
         $('#inputText_infoBox p').html('O endereço de e-email parece válido');
    else 
         $('#inputText_infoBox p').html('O endereço de e-email parece inválido');
  }
});
```

Comment: Code checks good - Thanx! One more question: I can I pass it to my Send button activation? Basically the Send button is a animated function - it begins disabled ('red cross') and, when all input fields are validated, it turns into a 'green envelope'. How do I pass it?

Comment: Uhm… wait let me get this straight: you want to validate once again on clicking of the Send button, or you want that on `blur` event your send button becomes available?

Comment: The Send button as two states: disabled (a 'red cross') and enabled (a 'green envelope'). When all fields are good to go (validated) the button enables itself (function) - the 'red cross' turns into the 'green envelope'. When this happens, clicking the 'green envelope' sends the email and resets all fields. So, I was thinking on making the validation through the blur in all fields. Hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: You can add to your validation `if/else` statement another line that changes the `class` of your submit button. Then style the classes to have a `background-image` of your choice (red cross/green envelope) and switch between them when validated/invalidated. After that bind an event handler to your submit button click which does the last validation and `return false` if invalid, or submit if valid.

Comment: :) I already have the buttons built - all the code is in place. I just need something like the original post request: what and where to put it, in the fields blur, that is.

Comment: Well, in order to answer that, I have to see the code that implements your form submitting or chaging of states. If you have a working link, this might be easy, if you don't, you may want to open a new question so we can discuss the solution there.

Comment: Ok then. I better finish the contact form first and then open a new discussion. Sunyatasattva, you have been incredibly helpfull. Thank you so much. :D

Comment: No problem. I hope I catch your next question when it comes up! :) Keep up the good work!

Comment: Hi there @Sunyatasattva. Here's the continuation [Need help implementing php code for contact form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152700/need-help-implementing-php-code-for-contact-form)

Answer (score 1):

I made an alternative solution which should be easier to expand. You can see it live on http://jsbin.com/eyimis/1/ and the code here: http://jsbin.com/eyimis/1/edit

It also has the ability to show the submit button once all the inputs are validated.

```
var test = {
  // Email
  'email' : {
    'validate' : 0,
    'fn' : function(emailAddress) {
      var pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\ ".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA -Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    }
  },
  // First and last name
  'name' : {
    'validate' : 0,
    'fn' : function(name) {
      name = name.split(' ');
      // Does it contain two names?
      return name.length > 1 && name[1].length > 0;
    }
  }
}, $error = $('#inputText_infoBox p');

var ready = function () {
  // How many inputs do we have to validate?
  var inputs = $.map(test, function(n, i) { return i; }).length, score = 0;
  for(var key in test) {
    // If this input is validated, we have ourselves a score!
    if(test[key].validate === 1) {
      score++;
    }
    // Is the amount of scores equal to to amount of inputs?
    if(score === inputs) {
      return true; 
    }
  }
};

$('input[type=text]').on({
  /* We'll check against a validate function every time the user
  press a key, depending on what field the user is interacting with */
  keyup: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Run the validate function for this particular input field
    if(test[$this.attr('id')].fn($this.val())) {
      // Validation returned true, yay! :)
      test[$this.attr('id')].validate = 1;
      $this.css({'background-color': '#00f000'});
      $error.html('');
    } else {
      // It returned false :(
      test[$this.attr('id')].validate = 0;
      $this.css({'background-color': '#ffffff'});
    }
    if(ready()) {
      $('#inputText_infoBox').after().html($('<input type="submit">'));
    } else {
      $button = $('input[type="submit"]');
      if(typeof $test !== undefined) {
        $button.remove();
      }
    }
  },
  /* We'll do the check for empty text fields on blur to
  avoid annoying errors */
  blur: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Only run if input hasn't validated yet
    if(test[$this.attr('id')].validate === 0) {
      if($.trim($this.val()) === '') {
        $error.html('Empty field');
      }
      // The input got to be invalid!
      else {
       $error.html('Your ' + $this.attr('id') + ' is invalid'); 
      }
    } 
    // It validated, clear error messages 
    else {
      $error.html(''); 
    }
  }
});
```